# Why does this code cause an error?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, connection, sqlclient

I have been looking for hours on how to connect to my local SQL database. I can't believe its been this difficult. Anyway, i think I am more on the right track with this code.

```
<%
    Dim myConnection as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    myConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True")
    myConnection.Open()
%>
```

However, It still does not work. I don't know where to begin because I also get this message when the page loads:

*Runtime Error*

**Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I created a web.config file, and it didn't change anything. I'm so lost. Any help is appreciated!

> Stack Trace: [SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Cannot open database
>   "dbtest" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user
>   'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +6244425    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +245
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2811
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) +53
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection
>   owningObject) +248
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
>   +6260362    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   +6260328    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +354
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +703
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +54
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +6261592
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +81
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +1657
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +88
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory) +6265031
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   +258    ASP.index_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) +71    System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +115
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +38
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4240

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's here

> Cannot open database "dbtest"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'IIS
>   APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'

The App Pool identity account is set up in SQL Server but is not set up in the database dbtest. You get a different error message if you could not connect to the SQL Server instance, but you are connecting for you to get this error message above.1

So, in SQL:

```
USE dbtest
GO
CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] FROM LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```

Edit:

When you connect to a "database", you actually authenticate 3 times (basically)

1. To the Windows/domain install hosting the SQL Server Instance (out of scope here)
2. To the SQL Server instance, where you are a "login" set up SQL Server via CREATE LOGIN
3. This login maps to zero or more databases as a "user", which is what you needed to do here

In this case, you were set up in SQL Server as a login but not set up in the target database hosted within the SQL Server instance.

Comment: Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Windows NT user or group 'IISAPPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' not found. Check the name again

Comment: This requires the caveat that he be especially careful about which objects and which commands he gives permission to in the database.

Comment: It has a space between IIS and APPPOOL.

Comment: THANK YOU!! IT WORKS 

Although can someone explain to me the origin of this error? It was all very confusing.

Comment: @Liam, the web page does not run under your account, it runs under another more limited account for security reasons -- specifically so that web pages can't do dangerous things. By default, the database doesn't have a login for this limited account -- why would it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the CustomError tag and value properly, like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will expose the exact issue to you.

Comment: It does print the stack, however I dont know what to make of it

Comment: So the user logon to the database failed (seen in your trace output). Put in the actual user id and password in the connection string. The user being used is IIS apppool [user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool']

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Data Source=(local)

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the instructions and made sure the customerErrors tag in the web.config looks like this:

`<customErrors mode="Off" />`

And the real error appears to be that the user ASP.Net is running as does not have permission to log in to the database.

Comment: Yes, it caused an error on that line. For some reason that code doesn't work

Comment: If you set customErrors to Off in your web.config you will get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Nevermind, i tried again and that printed the stack trace for me.